# Mongoose stopped work with typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose-schema

Mongoose static method `findByFacebookId` no longer functions. No error or result are produced, the `findOne()` callback function is never called and so far the promise is stuck in 'pending'. The unchanged code syntax, was previously functional before I passed typescript through it.

```
import { Document, Schema, Model, model} from "mongoose";

let PersonsSchema = new Schema({
  fbToken: String,
  fbId: Number,
  name: String
});

PersonsSchema.statics.findByFacebookId = function(id) {
  let _self = this;
  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    _self.findOne({ 'fbId': id }, function (err, person) {
      if (err) 
        reject(err);
      else
        resolve(person);
    });
  });
  return promise;
}
export default model<any>("Persons", PersonsSchema);

//findByFacebookId call
getPersonInfo(data) {
    return FbRestServices.getUserInfo(data.access_token).then((payload) => {
      return PersonsModel.findByFId(payload.id).then((person) => {});
```

Comment: findByFId or findById ?

Comment: findByFId (which stands for findByFacebookId, a field in my mongodDB collection)

Comment: Any particular reason you're creating a new promise? The method could be just `return this.findOne({ fbId: id });`. Also, can you share the code where the `findByFacebookId` method is called?

Comment: https://github.com/TheNemus/cornflakes/blob/master/src/lib/services/userDataManager.js r:24

Comment: you'r right, the promise is unnecessary